# Kubectl get pods does not return control plane pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

```
Kubectl get cs -o ymal
```

returns the healthy status for the control plane, but due some some reason,

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

does not show any control plane pods like api-server, schedular, controller manager etc.

I can also see the manifest file at /etc/kubernetes/manifests location as well.

Please help what am I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answers.

Although control plane components run as pods but nodes that runs the control plane
components are not registered in the the cluster as node. That is the reason, Kube API server does not have information about these nodes.

Answer (score 4):

GKE does not run the control plane in pods. Google does not really talk about how they run it but it's likely as containers in some GKE-specific management system.

Comment: This is not only true for GKE onprem but GKE on aws as well. Where we have full control on master node. I ssh into master node and could not find control plane in services form as well.